Rectangle Slicing Optimization Like Rectangle Packing Problem
I have an optimization project. In this project, I am working with a cardboard cutting machine. I need to optimize the layout of the desired final products on the cardboard. The machine needs to cut all the way along the axis it is cutting. How can I optimize this process accordingly? Is there an algorithm for this?
Packed rectangles
Rectangles and bin
Thanks in advance for your helps and opinions.
I tried rectpacking algoritms such as Best-Fit Decreasing. However I have to think the the cutting line must be continuous.
